# Running Multiple Instances of megasync in Linux

Tags: linux, cloud, storage

I would like to know if there is a way to run multiple megasync, the cloud storage sync tool from MEGA.co.nz, because I have 2 different accounts, one personal and another for all my family.

I'm running ArchLinux in my computer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change environment variable $HOME for each megasync instance. that you want to load.

I've created a simple example [script](https://gist.github.com/arthurafarias/401ae5fbbb76a4e1e5e5) to that. It loads a mega.co.nz client inside each folder inside the path that contains the script.

Answer (score 5):

As Arthur said, you just need to change $HOME for each instance.

I've created a [script](https://github.com/bssec/MEGA-Instances) for Ubuntu that will help you through the configuration. It may also run on Arch -I think-, just check you have megasync and zenity installed.